# What does this use of まいな mean?

Tags: translation, verbs, sentence-final-particles

[image]

忘れちゃおるまいな

From context he seems to be asking "You didn't forget how much I apologize to the dude"? But I'm not sure about this specific use.

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/96027/9831 /  https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/5574/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/77103/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/4761/9831

Answer (score 1):

な is the particle for inviting confirmation; ～まい is a borrowing from literary Japanese that has the force of ～ないだろう, so here おるまい is formally equivalent to おらないだろう. This latter form may not be used but the sense is clear.

Comment: おる also has an old vibe when used not as a humble verb.